# Why is $(n - 1)\binom{n - 2}{j - 2}$ different from $\binom{n - 1}{j - 1}$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

If I have $(n-1)\binom{n-2}{j-2}$ how is this different from $\binom{n-1}{j-1}$. Clearly the equations are different when solving it out, but can someone give me an explanation about why they are different?

Comment: Why would you expect them to be the same?

Comment: Let's say I was placing $j-1$ objects in $n-1$ spots. If I place the first object I have $n-1$ places to place it. Then, I have $n-2$ places to place the remaining $j-2$. However, why is this different from just placing $j-1$ objects in $n-1$ spots?

Comment: Work it out for small cases.  The problem is that you are counting the same configuration multiple times.

Comment: The binomial coefficient $\binom{n-1}{j-1}$ is the number of ways to place $n$ objects into $j$ bins, such that each bin has to have at least 1 object. But there's nothing saying I can't place multiple objects in the same bin. And on top of that, if you want to allow for empty bins, that's a whole different formula.

Comment: I'm still really confused :(

Comment: OK I'll type an answer and start from the beginning ... :)

Answer (score 1):

OK I think it's best to start from the beginning, with what the binomial coefficient actually represents.

The binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ represents the number of ways you can choose $k$ objects out of a set of $n$ objects, without replacement. Its formula is
$$
  \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
$$

So for example, if I have the numbers $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$, and I have to choose two of them, where the order doesn't matter, and where I can't choose the same number twice (i.e. "combinations", "without replacement"), the number of ways I can do that is $\binom{5}{2} = 10$. You can verify this by counting the actual ways:
$$(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)$$

The way that this translates into "placing objects into bins", is frequently thought of through the [stars & bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Proofs_via_the_method_of_stars_and_bars) approach. The "stars & bars" is a heuristic that allows you to translate the concept of "choosing combinations" into "placing items into bins" - but they aren't the same thing, per se.

The way it works is that you think of the items you are going to be placing into bins, plus the (let's say) "dividers" between the bins, together as just two types of "item". It's a bit convoluted, but it's like imagining that you're "building" the whole structure of the items in the bins all at once - both the items, *and* the bins. It's kind of like if you imagined building a bookshelf in reverse, by placing the books there first (maybe they hover, idk) and then sticking the shelves between them, instead of the usual real-life way of putting books onto a preexisting shelf.

There are two common cases. The first is where you specify that at least 1 item must go in each bin. Of course, for this to work, you have to have more items than bins. Let's say you have $5$ items and $3$ bins. Here are your items:
$$
 \bigstar \; \underline{\hspace{1ex}} \; \bigstar \; \underline{\hspace{1ex}} \; \bigstar \; \underline{\hspace{1ex}} \; \bigstar \; \underline{\hspace{1ex}} \; \bigstar
$$

To divide those items into $3$ bins, you have to "build" $3-1=2$ total walls ("bars"), in the $5-1=4$ blanks that exist between the items. (We only need to build $2$ walls for $3$ bins, because the walls on the outside are not necessary; they exist by default.) Where you choose to build the walls, will end up defining how many items go into each bin. Ah, but "choose" makes you think of "n choose k", does it not? There are $5-1=4$ total possible blanks to build these walls in, and $3-1=2$ total walls (or shelves, or bars, or whatever) to build. Hence the number of ways to place $5$ items into $3$ bins, where each bin must have at least one item, is: $$\binom{5-1}{3-1} = \binom{4}{2} = 6$$

This is not the same thing as the number of combinations - it is simply a way of *reinterpreting* combinations in order to count items in bins. The other difference to note is that for "items in bins", the items are indistinguishable - whereas the type of reasoning you mentioned in your comment, where you place the first item, then the second item, etc. usually ends up applying to cases where the items are distinguishable.

I think this hopefully clears up some of your confusion. There is another way to use "stars & bars", to count as $\binom{n+k-1}{n}$ the ways to place $n$ items into $k$ bins where bins can be empty. It is listed under "Theorem two" on the linked Wiki article, and it's essentially the same thing, with some slight tweaks.